# What happened to my Outlook preview pane?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I logged in this morning, my Outlook inbox preview pane is no longer showing like it used to. Here is what it looks like now:

[image]

But my Junk mail still shows it the old (and preferred) way:

[image]

I played around with all the View setting I could find and nothing seems to get it back to normal. I'm assuming this is an easy fix, but I couldn't find anything online about it.

Comment: The settings for Preview is in a little block to the right side of the Message Preview icon.  If not there, go to Control Panel, Programs and Features and run an Office Repair.. That will normally fix the Office menu and layout.

Comment: @John Thanks for the info. I played with the Preview settings and even did a repair with no luck. Strangely, this same thing happened to my Outlook on a different computer so I am assuming it is part of an update. I just can't find much information about it yet..

Comment: I have Office (Microsoft) 365 here and fully up-to-date and Preview is there.  What version of Office are you using?

Comment: @John Looks like version 365 MSO (16.0.12730.20144). Strange.. I may just have to try a complete reinstall. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I would try that. I have Office 365 on three machines here with no issue.  Also have not heard from any clients about this.

Comment: On the left of the view ribbon, you have 3 buttons for changing the view. You can also reset the view to the standard. Playing with these views or resetting it should give you your view back. You should be in Compact view, and it seems like you are in detailed view.

Comment: @LPChip Resetting it did the trick! Not sure how it got that way in the first place but I am just happy to have it back. You're fantastic!

Answer (score 6):

As always, this has an easy solution. Thank you LPChip for the answer.

Simply go to the View tab and use the 'Reset View' button in conjunction with setting the view to 'Compact' mode.

Comment: if you don't see _reset view_, go to _current view_ -> _view settings_ and then _reset current view_

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works. 
I also didn't find "Reset view" on the panel. I Search bar to locate it.

Comment: This cleared the issue run outlook.exe /safe on windows+R. there is a space between exe and /

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve this problem was simply LOGOUT and log back in.  POOF! Outlook fired up perfectly.

What I did previously was clear nav pane and reset nav pane previous to logging out.  That did work which, as a programmer, I simply thought to log out.

WALA! Like Tony Shalub said in Galaxy Quest: "It's the simple things..."

Answer (score 1):

Click on views, change views, select compact, click on manage views, click modify, click on reset current view, click ok.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the top answer? If you want to express that a different answer works, use the upvote button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Reset View is grayed out, I tried running "outlook.exe /cleanviews" but no luck, still only seeing partial views of the reading pane.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1129463)

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't directly apply to the specific situation in the question, but may help future searchers: The compact view in the preview pane will automatically switch between the two rendering layouts based on width of the pane. Make the preview pane wide, and it should/might show the table with column headers (like first screenshot in the question). Make the preview pane narrow, and it should/might go back (like the second screenshot).

Answer (score -1):

Go to view settings in the top left corner, click other settings, then ensure the checkbox "use compact layout in width...." is checked! then you'll be set!